# Doctrine/DQL fill a column with another

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql, query-builder

I have an entity Joke : id (int), body (text), vote (int), category(join entity)), and another entity JokeVote : id (int), anonymousUserID (int), vote (int). So anonymous user can attribute vote to each joke. But when I list the jokes, I would like to associate them, the joke of the current user :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('j', 'c', 'jv.vote')
    ->from($this->getClassName(), 'j', 'j.id')
    ->innerJoin('j.category', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('MyBundle:JokeVote', 'jv', 'WITH', 'jv.joke = j.id AND jv.anonymousUserID = :anonymousUser')
    ->setParameter('anonymousUser', 3);
```

The result :

```
array()
    0 => array(0 => array('id' => 2, 'body' => ..., 'vote' => null, category => ...), 'vote' => 1),
    1 => array(0 => array('id' => 6, 'body' => ..., 'vote' => null, category => ...), 'vote' => -1),
    2 => array(0 => array('id' => 4, 'body' => ..., 'vote' => null, category => ...), 'vote' => 1),
)
```

By doing this, the joke.vote value is not replaced by the jv.vote value. I would like :

```
array(
    0 => array('id' => 2, 'body' => ..., 'vote' => 1, category => ...),
    1 => array('id' => 6, 'body' => ..., 'vote' => -1, category => ...),
    2 => array('id' => 4, 'body' => ..., 'vote' => 1, category => ...),
)
```

How I can do this with createQueryBuilder and without rawSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: you can't. The Doctrine ORM querybuilder is specifically for returning full entities to you and even though the columns have the same name within your database tables, Doctrine is "smart" enough not to confuse the two.

The query that you're building is turned into DQL (which is turned into SQL) and because you're including single columns as well as entities, the result is "mixed" rather than "pure" ([documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results)). This is why you're getting the array of arrays as a result.

If you want what the result you'd like, you can either use [named native queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-named-native-query) within your mapping or you do a subsequent iteration on the results, e.g.

```
$result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
$ret = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $row[0]->setVote($row['vote']);
    $ret[] = $row[0];
}

return $ret;
```

This is one of those cases where an ORM (or just Doctrine) is going to get in your way more than you would perhaps expect.